# Node.JS append JSON to array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I need to append my JSON data to an array inside a JSON file. It is appending successfully. However, it does not append inside of the Brackets in the JSON file

Here is my **NODE**

```
 if (req.method == 'POST') {
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        fs.writeFile("comments-data.json", chunk, {'flag':'a'}, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }

            console.log("The file was saved!");
        })
    });
    res.end('{"msg": "success"}');
};
```

How can i tell it to just append inside of the brackets?

Comment: What brackets? What are you talking about?

Comment: You can't just append to a JSON file and expect it to merge into the array. You need to read the file, parse the JSON to an array, push the new element onto the array, stringify the array, and then write that to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the JSON in both the request and the file, push the requrest data onto the array, then write that back out to the file.

```
if (req.method == 'POST') {
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var element = JSON.parse(chunk);
        fs.readFile("comments-data.json", 'r', function(err, json) {
            var array = JSON.parse(json);
            array.push(element);
            fs.writeFile("comments-data.json", JSON.stringify(array), "w", function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log("The file was saved!");
            });
        });
        res.end('{"msg": "success"}');
    });
}
```

Comment: You were missing a }); at the end. Also it did not recognize 'r' so i changed it to utf8. When I try to run this snippet, I receive cannot read property push of null. @Barmar

Comment: That means `JSON.parse()` is failing, so there's something wrong with the contents of the json file.

Comment: How should it be setup for the example of your snippet? I tried even a blank array.

Comment: The initial contents of the file should be `[]`.

Comment: Same result with the blank array

Comment: What is the value of `json`? Is it the correct contents of the file?

Comment: Yeah when I add    console.log(element);
it appears to be the correct JSON

Comment: What about `console.log(json)`?

Comment: I got the arguments to the callback wrong, there's an `error` argument before the data.

Comment: works great when I remove the "w" from writefile. Thanks for the help!